# How do I search a webpage for element using PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, dom

I want to search a webpage for `<div class="contents">`, then I want to sort the data in a `foreach` block and save it to a file, I'm pretty sure how to do the latter but I need help with the initial *searching* of the webpage.

Thanks.

P.S. there are multiple `<div class="contents">` elements on the webpage and I'm going to go through them all with a `foreach` block also.

Comment: PHP has the [`DOM` library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for just such an occasion.

Comment: I know, I tagged the question with `dom`, could you post example code, please?

Comment: So did you give it a try? Where's your attempt?

Comment: I wanted to see code that wasn't a patch-up of mine own - that's all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its easy to work with simple_html_dom with PHP. for example:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

[See PHP Dom Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a check tomorrow and tell you if it worked, it looks like it should've.